# AADSTS50042: The salt required to generate a pairwise identifier is missing in the principal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365

I created a web application to process data inside Office 365 organization. The application is registered in Azure AD portal. I use [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to request tokens from Microsoft. It works fine in case of interaction with default Office 365 deployment. However, I can't obtain tokens while working with [germany Office 365 setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/admin-overview/learn-about-office-365-germany?view=o365-germany).

When I execute the next request
[image]
I get the next error

```
{
    "error": "server_error",
    "error_description": "AADSTS50042: The salt required to generate a pairwise identifier is missing in the principal.\r\nTrace ID: 2700e09a-b4a8-4081-b1b5-3e598ad01800\r\nCorrelation ID: 2ff3954f-066f-41e4-b72a-7039aca83497\r\nTimestamp: 2021-02-12 13:40:21Z",
    "error_codes": [
        50042
    ],
    "timestamp": "2021-02-12 13:40:21Z",
    "trace_id": "2700e09a-b4a8-4081-b1b5-3e598ad01800",
    "correlation_id": "2ff3954f-066f-41e4-b72a-7039aca83497",
    "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.de/error?code=50042"
}
```

What is the reason of this behavior? How can it be fixed?

Comment: Where did you register your AD App? `https://portal.microsoftazure.de/`? or `https://portal.azure.com/`?

Comment: I registered the application in https://portal.microsoftazure.de.